# Doesn't NoSQL databases work the same as an SQL Table with serialized objects in it?

Tags: sql, json, serialization, nosql

If I just store serialized JSON strings of objects in an SQL database table... does that turn it into a NoSQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might say that, but SQL databases are not designed to be NoSQL databases and vice versa.

What I'm trying to say is you can use a Ferrari to go grocery shopping, but it is not designed to do that and you can smash the pedal to the metal on a Kia on the highway but it is not designed to do that.

JSON strings in SQL databases are used to provide certain leverage and help in a RELATIONAL, WELL DEFINED data environment and should be used only like that. In other words if you need some data to be available on every record in some table, to avoid making a lot of joins, or that data cannot be defined (logs) you can leverage the power of serialized JSON strings in a SQL database.